# Problems with TEST-NET

Tags: synchronization, testnets

I'm newbie in the blockchain and ethereum technologies.

I have an account created in Ethereum Wallet inside the Test-NET network, my problem is the syncronitzaction with the peers.

In my personal computer work fine with my house network connection, but in other connection doesn't work fine some days works and connect and syncronise and others doesn't works, with other's computers doesn't connect just work with my personal computer, where is the problem with this network?

I've tried this:

- Open the ports.
- Change the antivirus and firewall of the computers.
- Test on the networks.
- Uninstall and install again the program.
- I tried the same with Mist.

PD: In the others computers just work well the main network of Ethereum and the Test-NEt doesn't work.

Comment: Hi there. When you say "Test-NET network", which specific testnet are you connecting to? When you are having problems, are you able to ping the outside world at all? Are you able to ping your peers in the network?

Comment: The default Test-net of the ethereum wallet, yes i can ping the outside is not a network problem is only with the test-net. I can't ping the peer in the test-net but i can ping the peers on the main network of ethereum

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure what the problem will be, to be honest. Which version of the Wallet and Geth are you using?

Comment: The last version, 0.8.9. and 1.5.9 of geth

Comment: @RichardHorrocks can be a problem if the pc are connected to domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for days ... The new actulization of geth version 1.6 has solved the problem.

Can be upgraded automatically when opening the Mist or Ethereum Wallet.

You can see the version changes and download directly from [here.](https://ethereum.github.io/go-ethereum/downloads/)

If someone thinks he knows which of the changes has solved the problem, he would be grateful if he would also put it in the comments or in this reply.